# Email To Print Issue Infinite loop

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, gmail

Having issues trying to get this code to work. It seems like the pdf it generates in google drive gets stuck in a loop. Each time the script runs it adds to the pdf rather than making a new pdf. I am not that advanced in code so I cant seem to fix this. I went back to the original code and its still happening. TO me it seems either like cache issue or that the temp html file is not getting deleted.

```
function AUTOPRINTV3() { 

var gmailLabels  = "AUTOPRINTV3";  
var driveFolder  = "Incoming Orders 2";

var threads = GmailApp.search("in:" + gmailLabels, 0, 5);  

if (threads.length > 0) {

/* Google Drive folder where the Files would be saved */
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(driveFolder);
var folder = folders.hasNext() ? 
    folders.next() : DriveApp.createFolder(driveFolder);

/* Gmail Label that contains the queue */
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gmailLabels) ?     
    GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gmailLabels) : GmailApp.createLabel(driveFolder);

for (var t=0; t<threads.length; t++) {

  threads[t].removeLabel(label);
  var msgs = threads[t].getMessages();

  var html = "";
  var attachments = [];

  var subject = threads[t].getFirstMessageSubject();

  /* Append all the threads in a message in an HTML document */
  for (var m=0; m<msgs.length; m++) {

    var msg = msgs[m];

    html += "From: " + msg.getFrom() + "<br />";  
    html += "To: " + msg.getTo() + "<br />";
    html += "Date: " + msg.getDate() + "<br />";
    html += "Subject: " + msg.getSubject() + "<br />"; 
    html += "<hr />";
    html += msg.getBody().replace(/<img[^>]*>/g,"");
    html += "<hr />";

    var atts = msg.getAttachments();
    for (var a=0; a<atts.length; a++) {
      attachments.push(atts[a]);
    }
  }

  /* Save the attachment files and create links in the document's footer */
  if (attachments.length > 0) {
    var footer = "<strong>Attachments:</strong><ul>";
    for (var z=0; z<attachments.length; z++) {
      var file = folder.createFile(attachments[z]);
      footer += "<li><a href='" + file.getUrl() + "'>" + file.getName() + "</a></li>";
    }
    html += footer + "</ul>";
  }

  /* Conver the Email Thread into a PDF File */
  var tempFile = DriveApp.createFile("temp.html", html, "text/html");
  folder.createFile(tempFile.getAs("application/pdf")).setName(subject + ".pdf");
  tempFile.setTrashed(true);

     }
   }
}
```

Comment: script is working perfectly....don't see any issue